# Difference between --append and --incremental append in sqoop

Tags: sqoop

Is there any difference between using --append and --incremental append for inserting new rows from RDBMS to an existing dataset in HDFS? I am using --append along with --where and --incremental append along with --last-value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`--append`  Append data to an existing dataset in HDFS

```
--append 
--where "dpt_id >10"
```

is same as: (**ONLY appends the data to existing data-sets**, **can also append duplicates** - NOTE: this will NOT overwrite the data but will append):

```
--incremental append
--check-column dpt_id
--last-value 10
```

but NOT following options (**Appends the new data and Updates the existing data** - **NO duplicates** - NOTE: this will not overwrite the data but will update OR append)

```
--incremental lastmodified
--check-column lastupdated
--last-value 20160802000000
```

Sqoop supports two types of `incremental` imports: `append` and `lastmodified`.

You can use the `--incremental` argument to specify the type of incremental import to perform.

***append:***

- You should specify `append` mode when importing a table where **new rows are continually being added with increasing row id values.**
- You specify the column containing the row’s id with `--check-column`.
- Sqoop imports rows where the check column has a value greater than the one specified with `--last-value`.

***lastmodified:***

- An alternate table update strategy supported by Sqoop is called `lastmodified` mode. **You should use this when rows of the source table may be updated**, and each such update will set the value of a last-modified column to the current timestamp.
- Rows where the check column holds a timestamp more recent than the timestamp specified with `--last-value` are imported.
- When running a subsequent import, you should specify `--last-value` in this way to ensure you import only the new or updated data.
- This is handled automatically by creating an incremental import as a saved job, which is the preferred mechanism for performing a recurring incremental import.

[read more about incremental_imports here. . .](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_incremental_imports)

Answer (score 1):

Specifying

```
--incremental lastmodified
```

Will generate the update statements thus will update the row if it exists depending on the column mentioned in

```
--checkcolumn
```

While mentioning

```
--incremental append
```

will insert duplicate records as it will only append